# How to run PHP files on XAMMP on A Mac

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I have saved a PHP file to my Applications/XAMMP/htdocs directory and I want to run it in a browser.

I have used all sorts of url combinations  including:
http://localhost/xammp/htdocs/HelloWord.php
http://localhost/xammp/HelloWord.php

amongst others and I cannot find the right url.

I am using  XAMPP on a Mac Majove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the XAMPP VM version, then you can probably access it via http://192.168.64.2/HelloWord.php (check the *General* tab in the XAMPP app for the IP address)

If you installed the native version, then I guess it is
http://localhost/HelloWord.php

The `htdocs/` folder is the document root. Its content is served under the server address. Neither the `xampp` nor the `htdocs` folder will be part of the URL. The paths are relative to the document root, and you shouldn't be able to access parent directories above `htdocs/` (although server-side code such as PHP has access to the file system and may work with files outside of the document root).

Comment: do you know what is the right route to add the following... I have an `index.php` and I need another file inside index: `class.php`... If I do this `require_once("class/class.php");` I only get 500 (internal server error), help :(

Answer (score 2):

First of all, expecting the php file to have information that can be visualized in a web browser, inside xampp if you have the .php file in the htdocs folder you should be able to visualize it like this:

http://localhost/HelloWord.php

Answer (score 1):

Found it by trial and error, quite different from what I  took from various instructions on line:

http://localhost/HelloWord.php

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP's default root should be "htdocs" or "www". Put your PHP files into those folder and try again.

if it is not work, find the configuration of Apache and PHP in XAMPP folder.